# Accessing "this" in a javascript forEach function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a particular scenario where I want to access data from "this" while looking through an array that is also defined on my Vue component. Example:

```
 data () {
    return {
      question: [],
      inputList: [],
      form: {}
    }
  },
 methods: {
   onSubmit: function () {
     let predictionParams = {}

     this.inputList.forEach(function (element) {
       predictionParams[element.detail] = this.form[element.detail]
     })
   }
```

Error:

```
this.form is not defined in the context of the forEach loop
```

Question:

What is the idiomatic JS way of handling a case like this? I run into this quite often and I always feel like I come up with sketchy solutions, or at the very least something easier could be done. Any help on this would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Many built-ins, including forEach include an optional 'this' binder:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

use that to your advantage:

```
this.inputList.forEach(function (element) {
   predictionParams[element.detail] = this.form[element.detail]
},this)
```

supported since ie9

Answer (score 1):

arrow function syntax avoids rebinding this

```
 this.inputList.forEach(element => {
   predictionParams[element.detail] = this.form[element.detail]
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Arrow function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions
It will binding this into the function

```
 data () {
    return {
      question: [],
      inputList: [],
      form: {}
    }
  },
 methods: {
   onSubmit: () => {
     let predictionParams = {}

     this.inputList.forEach((element) => {
       predictionParams[element.detail] = this.form[element.detail]
     })
   }
```

Comment: this is actually incorrect, and will break the this binding provided by vue